# gmake (Gnu) to make (Cygwin) - verification of my implementation [only 3 statements]

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make, gnu

I need to convert a makefile built for gmake into a makefile that could be executed via cygwin "make" command.

The GMAKE code is below:

```
OBJ := ${SOURCES:%.c=%.o}

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES)

$(LIBNAME).lib: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(OBJ)

clean:
    del $(OBJ)
    del *.out
```

I've used the statements below in the Cygwin makefile. Could you please confirm, if it replicates the gmake statements above or am I missing something. Any inputs would be helpful.

Cygwin "make":

```
OBJ := ${SOURCES:%.c=%.o}

%.obj: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o `cygpath -w $@` `cygpath -w $<` $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES)

.DEFAULT_GOAL := ${LIBNAME}.lib
${LIBNAME}.lib: $(OBJS) 
    $(SILENCE)echo -e "Archive: ${LIBNAME}.lib\n"
    $(SILENCE)$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) `cygpath -w $@` ${OBJS}} 

clean:
    rm $(OBJ)
    rm *.out
```

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: #1 cygwin make is gmake (Gnu Make). #2 `cygpath -w` is totally wrong for cygwin compilers. So what is not working in using the original code ?

Comment: Well, i'm using a makefile for code composer studio on windows10 platform & for some reason the makefile does not execute using gmake on the windows10 system (while with the same tool setup, it executes on a windows7 system).I had a cygwin version of another makefile and it executed well on the windows10 system.Unfortunately, this current makefile (using gmake posted in my original post),didn't have a cygwin equivalent, so I had to write one on my own and hence needed validation. Thanks for your inputs. Could you please elaborate #2 (cygpath -w) and what needs to be done instead. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @matzeri, cygwin make *is* gnu make.
That's why I use it.
The first makefile looks fine to me.

If all your files use relative paths, everything should be fine.
Even the Microsoft compiler can build `subdir/file.cpp` and stick the object into `objdir/file.o` (`cl subdir/file.cpp -o objdir/file.o`).

Hint: Strive manfully to use forward slashes in your filenames. Always.

The only difficulty you might have is with absolute paths,
as typically appear in include paths say.
`/usr/local/include` only makes sense to cygwin programs.
`cl.exe` would like this translated to `C:/cygwin64/usr/local/include`.

Don't use backslashes unless the command really *really* requires it.
One issue then is that *bash* interprets backslashes,
so you will have to quote the filename in some way to prevent this.

```
objdir/1.o: /usr/local/src/1.cpp
    some-odd-compiler "$$(cygpath -wa $<)" -o "$$(cygpath -w $@)"
```

Quoting not required if you use forward slashes (`cygpath -ma`).

Why prefer `$(…)` over `` `…` ``? Because then the double quotes nest.
Useful if the path in question expands to something with a space in it (`"$$(cygpath -wa "$<")"`)

Comment: Thank you for your comments on the code and your time!